# JpaRepository findOne(id) returns null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is my first post here, I've been searching for a long time here but I didn't found a problem that seemed similar.

When I use JpaRepository function findOne(id) for one of my classes, it returns null. As if no row had been found for this id.
Of course the database row with this id exists.

Also my class mapping seems right.

I don't understand because I already used findOne() for other classes and I never had any problem.

Anyone can tell me what can be the source of this problem, please ? That would be nice !

This is my DAO :

```
@Transactional
public interface OrderDetailDAO extends JpaRepository<OrderDetail, Integer>
{
}
```

This is my Model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_detail", schema = "", catalog = AppConfig.databaseSchema)
public class OrderDetail implements Serializable {
private int idOrderDetail;
private Order order;
private Preorder preorder;
private UnitType unitType;
private Sale sale;
private DeliveryStatusType deliveryStatusType;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_Order_Detail")
public int getIdOrderDetail() {
    return idOrderDetail;
}
public void setIdOrderDetail(int idOrderDetail) {
    this.idOrderDetail = idOrderDetail;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_Order", referencedColumnName = "id_Order", nullable = false)
public Order getOrder() {
    return order;
}
public void setOrder(Order order) {
    this.order = order;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_Preorder", referencedColumnName = "id_Preorder", nullable = false)
public Preorder getPreorder() {
    return preorder;
}
public void setPreorder(Preorder preorder) {
    this.preorder = preorder;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_Unit_Type", referencedColumnName = "id_Unit_Type")
public UnitType getUnitType() {
    return unitType;
}
public void setUnitType(UnitType unitType) {
    this.unitType = unitType;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_Sale", referencedColumnName = "id_Sale")
public Sale getSale() {
    return sale;
}
public void setSale(Sale sale) {
    this.sale = sale;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_Delivery_Status_Type", referencedColumnName = "id_Delivery_Status_Type")
public DeliveryStatusType getDeliveryStatusType() {
    return deliveryStatusType;
}
public void setDeliveryStatusType(DeliveryStatusType deliveryStatusType) {
    this.deliveryStatusType = deliveryStatusType;
}
}
```

When I write a request manually, like this :

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM OrderDetail o WHERE o.idOrderDetail = :idOrderDetail")
public OrderDetail findOneCustom(@Param("idOrderDetail") Integer idOrderDetail);
```

That works, but that's ugly so I would prefer to use JpaRepository native function findOne()

Comment: We need mode detail. Could you provide some part of the code ?

Comment: Whoa you answered quickly, thank you ! I edited my post

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldn't `idOrderDetail` (+ accessors) be an `Integer` instead of an `int`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer sp00m.
Indeed we can use Integer for hibernate mapping, but in all my other classes i also use int and findOne() works.

Comment: for starter change int to Integer, second, check in log what query is generated by hibernate when you call `findOne` method. this might be good place to start

Answer (score 1):

After all investigation, I have found an interesting answer that is worked for me. I think it is all about defining column type on Db. For my case, I have defined the variable (`rid` as column) as `varchar2(18)` that was `RID   CHAR(18 BYTE)`.

Java part:

```
if (dhFlightRepo.findOneFlight(dhFlight.getRid())== null) {       
    dhFlightRepo.save(dhFlight);
}
```

If your value that you used as a parameter for `findOne()` is smallest than set value on column (18 for my case),the jpa doesn't accept value and returns null.You have to change column type as varchar2(18) it can be  changeable according to given value on `findOne()` and work perfect.

I hope that works for all of you.I kindly request to give more detail If someone knows the reason with more detail.